# Proving unique solution for a higher dimension boundary value problem

Tags: partial-differential-equations, solution-verification, heat-equation

> Prove that the boundary value problem,
> \begin{cases}
> u_{t} -\nabla\cdot(k(x) \nabla u) = r(x,t) && \text{in } \Omega_{T},\\
> u(x,0) = g(x) && \text{in } \ \Omega,\\
> u(\sigma,t) = 0 && \text{in } \ \partial \Omega \times (0,T],
> \end{cases}
> has a unique solution. (Note: $k(x) > 0$.)

#### Attempt at solution

I must use the energy method in higher dimension, along with Green's identity. Let $w = u-v$ solve
\begin{cases}
u_{t} -\nabla\cdot(k(x) \nabla u) = 0 && \text{in } \Omega_{T},\\
u(x,0) = 0 && \text{in } \ \Omega,\\
u(\sigma,t) = 0 && \text{in } \ \partial \Omega \times (0,T],
\end{cases}
Then by the energy method , I want to show that $E'(t) \le  0 \implies E(t) \le 0 $, but by definition of energy $E(t) \ge 0$ which would imply that $w(x,t) \equiv 0$ from inside the integral.

\begin{align}
E(t) &:= \int_{\Omega} w^{2}(x,t) \ dx \\
E'(t) &= \int_{\Omega}\frac{d}{dt} w^{2} (x,t) \ dx \\
&=2 \int_{\Omega} w w_{t} \ dx\\
\end{align}
Using $w_{t} = \nabla \cdot(k(x) \nabla u)$,
\begin{align}
E'(t) &= 2\int_{\Omega} w (\nabla \cdot (k(x)\nabla w)) \ dx \\
&= 2\int_{\Omega} w (k(x) \Delta w + \nabla w \nabla k(x)) \ dx \\
&= 2 \int_{\Omega} w k(x) \Delta w \ dx + 2\int_{\Omega} w \nabla w \nabla k(x) \ dx
\end{align}
Greens Identity states that
$$ \int_{\Omega} w \Delta w \ dx = \int_{\partial \Omega} w \partial_{n} w \ d\sigma - \int_{\Omega} \lvert \nabla w \rvert^{2} \ dx$$
therefore,
\begin{align}
E'(t) &= 2 \int_{\partial \Omega} k(x) w \partial_{n} w \ d\sigma - 2\int_{\Omega} k(x) \lvert \nabla w \rvert^{2} \ dx + 2 \int_{\Omega} w \nabla w \nabla k \ dx
\end{align}
Since the given BVP has Dirichlet homogenous boundaries , the first term vanishes since $w \partial_{n} w = 0 $ on $\partial w$, therefore
$$ E'(t)=  - 2\int_{\Omega} k(x) \lvert \nabla w \rvert^{2} \ dx + 2 \int_{\Omega} w \nabla w \nabla k(x) \ dx.$$
Now if I show that the latter expression is less or equal to $0$ then I'm done. The first integral is evidently less than $0$ since $k(x) >0$ ,but  I don't know how to show that the second integral is less than the first or less than $0$, and I'm not sure if I went wrong somewhere in the proof.

#### Edit

I believe I found a solution.
\begin{align}
E'(t) &= 2\int_{\Omega} w(x) \text{div} (k(x) \nabla w) \\
&= 2\int_{\Omega} w(x) \sum_{i} (k(x) w_{x_{i}})_{x_{i}} \\
&= 2\int_{\partial \Omega} w(x) k(x) \sum_{i} w_{x_{i}} \ d\sigma - 2 \int_{\Omega} k(x)\sum_{i}(w_{x_{i}})^{2} \ dx \\
&= - 2 \int_{\Omega} k(x)\sum_{i}(w_{x_{i}})^{2} \ dx \\
E'(t) &= -2 \int_{\Omega} k(x) \Delta(w)^{2},
\end{align}
the rest follows.

I'm adding proof verification tag , if someone could confirm.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You used Green's identity wrong in differentiating $E$. It should be

$$E'(t) = 2\int_\Omega w(\nabla \cdot (k(x)\nabla w)) \, dx = -2\int_\Omega k(x)|\nabla w|^2\, dx$$

from which $E'(t)\leq 0$ is clear.

EDIT: The version of Green's identity I used is

$$\int_\Omega w \nabla F \, dx = \int_{\partial \Omega} w F\cdot \nu \, dS - \int_\Omega \nabla w \cdot F\,dx$$

for a vector field $F$ (here, $F=k\nabla w$), which is just the Divergence Theorem.

Comment: Thank you for your insight, I understand that  $$ \int_{\partial \Omega} wF \cdot \mu\ dS = 0,$$ since the boundaries are $0$. But I don't understand how you show that  $$ \int_{\Omega} \nabla w \cdot F \ dx = \int_{\Omega}k(x) \lvert \nabla w \rvert^{2} \ dx ?$$ Is $$ \nabla w \cdot (k(x)\nabla w) = k(x) \lvert \nabla w\rvert^2 ?$$ How could that be, $k$ is a fuction of $x$

Comment: There is no differentiation happening. You are dotting the vector field $\nabla w$ with $k\nabla w$. Since $k$ is a scalar, it can be factored out.

Comment: $k$ is defined as $k(x)$ , i.e., $k$ is a function of $x$, are you telling me $k(x)$ is a scalar ? I am so confused, if I'm differentiating with respect to $x$ $k(x)$ then I treat $k(x)$ as a scalar ?

Comment: It is a scalar function $k:\Omega \to \mathbb{R}$, compared to the gradient which is a vector function $\nabla u:\Omega \to \mathbb{R}^n$. The dot product is pointwise in $x$; it does not matter that $k$ is a function of $x$, just that it is a scalar. For any vectors $V,W$ and scalar $k$, $V\cdot (kW) = kV\cdot W$.

Comment: Wow I was really overcomplicating this trivial problem , thank you for helping !

Comment: You might be confused about the notation $\nabla w \cdot (k(x) \nabla w)$. It is the same as $(\nabla w) \cdot (k \nabla w)$, i.e., the $\nabla$ on the outside is not differentiating $k$.

Comment: Your welcome. It always appears too complicated until you understand:)